# createSQLQuery(String sqlQuery) Error in Spingboot2 to Springboot3 migration

Tags: spring-boot, java-17

I am doing the Springboot migration from **Springboot2** to **Springboot3** along with JAVA17, but while migration i am getting error in existing code for **createSQLQuery(String query)** .

so could anyone help me on replacing  **createSQLQuery(String query ) from Springboot2 with the Springboot3 subsequent method**?

```
 Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        String cmsLegacyLessonContent;
        Query<?> cmsLegacyContent = session.createSQLQuery(Select * from Dual);
```

but getting below error as :
**The method createSQLQuery(String) is undefined for the type Session.**

Comment: do not post screenshots, post the actual text. Firewalls tend to block things and images tend to disappear over time too.

Answer (score 1):

The hibernate version associated with spring boot3 is hibernate 6.X. In the new version of hibernate, there is no `session.createSQLQueryf` method. Try using `createQuery` instead.